# Image collage in recycler adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

I have a typical recycler adapter set up. Some of the items in the adapter have images, sometimes just one image, sometimes 20. I want to create an image collage, like the one below, depending on the number of images in each item:

[image]

I have 10 different layouts. The first is to be used when the item only has 1 image (1 `ImageView` in the layout), another used when the item has 2 images (2 `ImageViews` in the layout), another used when the item has 3 images, etc. If the item has over 10 images, it uses the layout with 10 `ImageViews` and hides the rest of the images. The layouts are named:

- one_image.xml
- two_images.xml
- three_images.xml
- ... etc ...

Here is my Recycler adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static Context context;
    private List<Message> mDataset;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Message> myDataset) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView title;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((LinearLayout) view);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message item = mDataset.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());

        int numImages = item.getImages().size();
        if (numImages > 0) {
            // Show image collage
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

Here is the main layout, `message_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    // Image collage layout

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is one of the image collage layouts, `two_images.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

So the question is, how do I load/inflate the correct layout depending on the number of images into the recycler adapter, and populate the layout with the images?

Comment: You don't scroll your layout right? You'd better write a custom ViewGroup

Comment: What do you mean by scroll? The main layout that the items are loaded into from the recycler adapter scrolls (it's a list of cards).

Comment: In which direction should it be scrollable? You should consider StaggeredGridLayoutManager in that case (see @Amit Kumar answer)

Comment: The image collage itself shouldn't be scrollable.

Comment: In that case, please consider the following libraries: https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout or https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout . For a perfect line up, you still need some self-customization.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well enough. I'm not looking on how to make the collage itself (I have the 10 layouts for that), I'm asking how to implement it in such a way that it loads the correct layout depending on the number of images per item and then inflates it.

Comment: I see. Well, in that case, take a look at getViewType of Adapter class. I think it is what you are looking for. Return number of image as view type, define specific viewholder for each of that type (see onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)).

Answer (score 2):

You can use StaggeredGridLayoutManager to achieve above type of layouts. [Click here for more information about StaggeredGridLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html)

There are a number of libraries for staggered gridview. you can use any of them. I recommend to use this: 
[AndroidStaggeredGrid](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom ViewHolder for each one of your layouts.

Imagine you have this ViewHolder: `TwoImagesViewHolder`

```
public class TwoImagesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView imageOne;
    public ImageView imageTwo;

    public TwoImagesViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        imageOne = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image_one);
        imageTwo = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image_two);
    }
}
```

Inside the adapter you can use your holder like this:

```
@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Message item = mDataset.get(position);
    int numImages = item.getImages().size();
    if (numImages == 2) {
        return new TwoImagesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_layout, parent, false))
    }

    // Add all the conditions for your custom ViewHolders 

    return DefaultViewHolder; // Define a Default holder 
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message item = mDataset.get(position);
    int numImages = item.getImages().size();
    if (numImages == 2) {
      // Show image collage
      TwoImagesViewHolder holder = (TwoImagesViewHolder)viewHolder;
      holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
      holder.image_one.setImageResource(...);
      holder.image_two.setImageResource(...);
    }

    // Add all the conditions for your custom ViewHolders 
}
```

You need to create all your conditions to instance the correct layout holder and remember to have the same conditions for the onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder.